# Inject mock object using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and Mockito into Aspect Class

Tags: java, spring, mockito, aop

I have a test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and this to initialize mockito:

```
@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Now I have an @Autowired field to get aspect advising it, but cannot inject mocks.

My aspect:

```
@Autowired
private MyMock myMock;
@Around("execution(* xxx.MyService.aspectMethod(..))")
public void process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    myMock.mockMethod();
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @Mock
    private MyMock myMock;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyAspectClass;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }    


    public void shouldXXXX() {

        doThrow(Exception.class).when(myMock).mockMethod();
        myService.aspectMethod();

        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

The issue is that the aspect triggered is not the same of what I'm mocking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was as simple as

```
@InjectMocks
    private MyAspectClass;
```